# useEffect dependency array with simple variable

Tags: reactjs, performance, react-hooks

Usually, I'm triggering useEffect with values from the state/props which I set in the dependency array.
My question is if it is a good practice also to use a simple variable (type of string/number) in the dependency array or I should avoid it because of side effects?

For example:

```
const MyComponent = () => {
   const currentTab = getTabFromPath(location.pathname)

   useEffect(() => {
     // do something
   }, [currentTab])
}
```

Comment: In fact using string/number are good candidates for a dependency array, in contrast to arrays and objects. However, your question is not clear: what do you mean by if using them as a good/bad idea to begin with? If you have logic that needs to be re-run because `currentTab` has changed, then you _must_ add it in your dependency array.

Answer (score 2):

You can use normal variables in the dependency array, just keep in mind that changing a variable will not cause a re-render. Why don't you just store `currentTab` in a state?

Comment: because I have another state that will be updated in the useEffect so I think it's cleaner with one usestate instead of two